# How can I use the Eclipse Paho JavaScript Client to connect to test.mosquitto.org?

Tags: javascript, mqtt, paho

I am new to the IOT world and have been confused why I have not been able to use the [Eclipse Paho JavaScript Client](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/js/utility/) to connect to test.mosquitto.org.

I have used Port: 8080 and Path: /mqtt as has been suggested in other paho-mqtt questions, but am met with a `Failed to connect: AMQJS0007E Socket error:undefined` when using this Eclipse web client.

I have used the [HiveMQ WebClient](http://www.hivemq.com/demos/websocket-client/) and have been able to connect, publish and subscribe to both test.mosquitto.org (Port 8080) and iot.eclipse.org (Port 443).

I have noticed that HiveMQ sources `mqttws31.js` compared to Paho Eclipse's `paho-mqtt.js`, but am unsure of the significance.

I would say there are two parts to this question:

1. What am I missing to get the Eclipse Paho JavaScript Client to connect to test.mosquitto.org ?
2. What is the difference between `mqttws31.js` and `paho-mqtt.js` that allows one to connect to test.mosquitto.org relatively painlessly compared to the other?

Thanks !

---

## Relevant Code:

The code below is taken directly from the page source of https://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/js/utility/

**paho-mqtt.js**: https://www.eclipse.org/paho/js/paho-mqtt.js

**utility.js** (handles button callbacks):

```
/*******************************************************************************
 * Copyright (c) 2015 IBM Corp.
 *
 * All rights reserved. This program and the accompanying materials
 * are made available under the terms of the Eclipse Public License v1.0
 * and Eclipse Distribution License v1.0 which accompany this distribution.
 *
 * The Eclipse Public License is available at
 *    http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html
 * and the Eclipse Distribution License is available at
 *   http://www.eclipse.org/org/documents/edl-v10.php.
 *
 * Contributors:
 *    James Sutton - Initial Contribution
 *******************************************************************************/

/*
Eclipse Paho MQTT-JS Utility
This utility can be used to test the Eclipse Paho MQTT Javascript client.
*/

// Create a client instance
var client = null;
var connected = false;


logMessage("INFO", "Starting Eclipse Paho JavaScript Utility.");

// Things to do as soon as the page loads
document.getElementById("clientIdInput").value = "js-utility-" + makeid();

// called when the client connects
function onConnect(context) {
  // Once a connection has been made, make a subscription and send a message.
  var connectionString = context.invocationContext.host + ":" + context.invocationContext.port + context.invocationContext.path;
  logMessage("INFO", "Connection Success ", "[URI: ", connectionString, ", ID: ", context.invocationContext.clientId, "]");
  var statusSpan = document.getElementById("connectionStatus");
  statusSpan.innerHTML = "Connected to: " + connectionString + " as " + context.invocationContext.clientId;
  connected = true;
  setFormEnabledState(true);
}


function onConnected(reconnect, uri) {
  // Once a connection has been made, make a subscription and send a message.
  logMessage("INFO", "Client Has now connected: [Reconnected: ", reconnect, ", URI: ", uri, "]");
  connected = true;


}

function onFail(context) {
  logMessage("ERROR", "Failed to connect. [Error Message: ", context.errorMessage, "]");
  var statusSpan = document.getElementById("connectionStatus");
  statusSpan.innerHTML = "Failed to connect: " + context.errorMessage;
  connected = false;
  setFormEnabledState(false);
}

// called when the client loses its connection
function onConnectionLost(responseObject) {
  if (responseObject.errorCode !== 0) {
    logMessage("INFO", "Connection Lost. [Error Message: ", responseObject.errorMessage, "]");
  }
  connected = false;
}

// called when a message arrives
function onMessageArrived(message) {
  logMessage("INFO", "Message Recieved: [Topic: ", message.destinationName, ", Payload: ", message.payloadString, ", QoS: ", message.qos, ", Retained: ", message.retained, ", Duplicate: ", message.duplicate, "]");
  var messageTime = new Date().toISOString();
  // Insert into History Table
  var table = document.getElementById("incomingMessageTable").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
  var row = table.insertRow(0);
  row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = message.destinationName;
  row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = safeTagsRegex(message.payloadString);
  row.insertCell(2).innerHTML = messageTime;
  row.insertCell(3).innerHTML = message.qos;


  if (!document.getElementById(message.destinationName)) {
    var lastMessageTable = document.getElementById("lastMessageTable").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
    var newlastMessageRow = lastMessageTable.insertRow(0);
    newlastMessageRow.id = message.destinationName;
    newlastMessageRow.insertCell(0).innerHTML = message.destinationName;
    newlastMessageRow.insertCell(1).innerHTML = safeTagsRegex(message.payloadString);
    newlastMessageRow.insertCell(2).innerHTML = messageTime;
    newlastMessageRow.insertCell(3).innerHTML = message.qos;

  } else {
    // Update Last Message Table
    var lastMessageRow = document.getElementById(message.destinationName);
    lastMessageRow.id = message.destinationName;
    lastMessageRow.cells[0].innerHTML = message.destinationName;
    lastMessageRow.cells[1].innerHTML = safeTagsRegex(message.payloadString);
    lastMessageRow.cells[2].innerHTML = messageTime;
    lastMessageRow.cells[3].innerHTML = message.qos;
  }

}

function connectionToggle() {

  if (connected) {
    disconnect();
  } else {
    connect();
  }


}


function connect() {
  var hostname = document.getElementById("hostInput").value;
  var port = document.getElementById("portInput").value;
  var clientId = document.getElementById("clientIdInput").value;

  var path = document.getElementById("pathInput").value;
  var user = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
  var pass = document.getElementById("passInput").value;
  var keepAlive = Number(document.getElementById("keepAliveInput").value);
  var timeout = Number(document.getElementById("timeoutInput").value);
  var tls = document.getElementById("tlsInput").checked;
  var automaticReconnect = document.getElementById("automaticReconnectInput").checked;
  var cleanSession = document.getElementById("cleanSessionInput").checked;
  var lastWillTopic = document.getElementById("lwtInput").value;
  var lastWillQos = Number(document.getElementById("lwQosInput").value);
  var lastWillRetain = document.getElementById("lwRetainInput").checked;
  var lastWillMessageVal = document.getElementById("lwMInput").value;


  if (path.length > 0) {
    client = new Paho.Client(hostname, Number(port), path, clientId);
  } else {
    client = new Paho.Client(hostname, Number(port), clientId);
  }
  logMessage("INFO", "Connecting to Server: [Host: ", hostname, ", Port: ", port, ", Path: ", client.path, ", ID: ", clientId, "]");

  // set callback handlers
  client.onConnectionLost = onConnectionLost;
  client.onMessageArrived = onMessageArrived;
  client.onConnected = onConnected;


  var options = {
    invocationContext: { host: hostname, port: port, path: client.path, clientId: clientId },
    timeout: timeout,
    keepAliveInterval: keepAlive,
    cleanSession: cleanSession,
    useSSL: tls,
    reconnect: automaticReconnect,
    onSuccess: onConnect,
    onFailure: onFail
  };



  if (user.length > 0) {
    options.userName = user;
  }

  if (pass.length > 0) {
    options.password = pass;
  }

  if (lastWillTopic.length > 0) {
    var lastWillMessage = new Paho.Message(lastWillMessageVal);
    lastWillMessage.destinationName = lastWillTopic;
    lastWillMessage.qos = lastWillQos;
    lastWillMessage.retained = lastWillRetain;
    options.willMessage = lastWillMessage;
  }

  // connect the client
  client.connect(options);
  var statusSpan = document.getElementById("connectionStatus");
  statusSpan.innerHTML = "Connecting...";
}

function disconnect() {
  logMessage("INFO", "Disconnecting from Server.");
  client.disconnect();
  var statusSpan = document.getElementById("connectionStatus");
  statusSpan.innerHTML = "Connection - Disconnected.";
  connected = false;
  setFormEnabledState(false);

}

// Sets various form controls to either enabled or disabled
function setFormEnabledState(enabled) {

  // Connection Panel Elements
  if (enabled) {
    document.getElementById("clientConnectButton").innerHTML = "Disconnect";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("clientConnectButton").innerHTML = "Connect";
  }
  document.getElementById("hostInput").disabled = enabled;
  document.getElementById("portInput").disabled = enabled;
  document.getElementById("clientIdInput").disabled = enabled;
  document.getElementById("pathInput").disabled = enabled;
  document.getElementById("userInput").disabled = enabled;
  document.getElementById("passInput").disabled = enabled;
  document.getElementById("keepAliveInput").disabled = enabled;
  document.getElementById("timeoutInput").disabled = enabled;
  document.getElementById("tlsInput").disabled = enabled;
  document.getElementById("automaticReconnectInput").disabled = enabled;
  document.getElementById("cleanSessionInput").disabled = enabled;
  document.getElementById("lwtInput").disabled = enabled;
  document.getElementById("lwQosInput").disabled = enabled;
  document.getElementById("lwRetainInput").disabled = enabled;
  document.getElementById("lwMInput").disabled = enabled;

  // Publish Panel Elements
  document.getElementById("publishTopicInput").disabled = !enabled;
  document.getElementById("publishQosInput").disabled = !enabled;
  document.getElementById("publishMessageInput").disabled = !enabled;
  document.getElementById("publishButton").disabled = !enabled;
  document.getElementById("publishRetainInput").disabled = !enabled;

  // Subscription Panel Elements
  document.getElementById("subscribeTopicInput").disabled = !enabled;
  document.getElementById("subscribeQosInput").disabled = !enabled;
  document.getElementById("subscribeButton").disabled = !enabled;
  document.getElementById("unsubscribeButton").disabled = !enabled;

}

function publish() {
  var topic = document.getElementById("publishTopicInput").value;
  var qos = document.getElementById("publishQosInput").value;
  var message = document.getElementById("publishMessageInput").value;
  var retain = document.getElementById("publishRetainInput").checked;
  logMessage("INFO", "Publishing Message: [Topic: ", topic, ", Payload: ", message, ", QoS: ", qos, ", Retain: ", retain, "]");
  message = new Paho.Message(message);
  message.destinationName = topic;
  message.qos = Number(qos);
  message.retained = retain;
  client.send(message);
}


function subscribe() {
  var topic = document.getElementById("subscribeTopicInput").value;
  var qos = document.getElementById("subscribeQosInput").value;
  logMessage("INFO", "Subscribing to: [Topic: ", topic, ", QoS: ", qos, "]");
  client.subscribe(topic, { qos: Number(qos) });
}

function unsubscribe() {
  var topic = document.getElementById("subscribeTopicInput").value;
  logMessage("INFO", "Unsubscribing: [Topic: ", topic, "]");
  client.unsubscribe(topic, {
    onSuccess: unsubscribeSuccess,
    onFailure: unsubscribeFailure,
    invocationContext: { topic: topic }
  });
}


function unsubscribeSuccess(context) {
  logMessage("INFO", "Unsubscribed. [Topic: ", context.invocationContext.topic, "]");
}

function unsubscribeFailure(context) {
  logMessage("ERROR", "Failed to unsubscribe. [Topic: ", context.invocationContext.topic, ", Error: ", context.errorMessage, "]");
}

function clearHistory() {
  var table = document.getElementById("incomingMessageTable");
  //or use :  var table = document.all.tableid;
  for (var i = table.rows.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    table.deleteRow(i);
  }

}


// Just in case someone sends html
function safeTagsRegex(str) {
  return str.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").
    replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
}

function makeid() {
  var text = "";
  var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

  return text;
}

function logMessage(type, ...content) {
  var consolePre = document.getElementById("consolePre");
  var date = new Date();
  var timeString = date.toUTCString();
  var logMessage = timeString + " - " + type + " - " + content.join("");
  consolePre.innerHTML += logMessage + "\n";
  if (type === "INFO") {
    console.info(logMessage);
  } else if (type === "ERROR") {
    console.error(logMessage);
  } else {
    console.log(logMessage);
  }
}
```

The code below is taken directly from the page source of http://www.hivemq.com/demos/websocket-client/

**mqttws31.js**: http://www.hivemq.com/demos/websocket-client/js/mqttws31.js

**app.js** (handles app callbacks):

```
/**
 * Copyright 2013 dc-square GmbH
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 *
 * @author: Christoph SchÃ¤bel
 */

var websocketclient = {
    'client': null,
    'lastMessageId': 1,
    'lastSubId': 1,
    'subscriptions': [],
    'messages': [],
    'connected': false,

    'connect': function () {

        var host = $('#urlInput').val();
        var port = parseInt($('#portInput').val(), 10);
        var clientId = $('#clientIdInput').val();
        var username = $('#userInput').val();
        var password = $('#pwInput').val();
        var keepAlive = parseInt($('#keepAliveInput').val());
        var cleanSession = $('#cleanSessionInput').is(':checked');
        var lwTopic = $('#lwTopicInput').val();
        var lwQos = parseInt($('#lwQosInput').val());
        var lwRetain = $('#LWRInput').is(':checked');
        var lwMessage = $('#LWMInput').val();
        var ssl = $('#sslInput').is(':checked');

        this.client = new Messaging.Client(host, port, clientId);
        this.client.onConnectionLost = this.onConnectionLost;
        this.client.onMessageArrived = this.onMessageArrived;

        var options = {
            timeout: 3,
            keepAliveInterval: keepAlive,
            cleanSession: cleanSession,
            useSSL: ssl,
            onSuccess: this.onConnect,
            onFailure: this.onFail
        };

        if (username.length > 0) {
            options.userName = username;
        }
        if (password.length > 0) {
            options.password = password;
        }
        if (lwTopic.length > 0) {
            var willmsg = new Messaging.Message(lwMessage);
            willmsg.qos = lwQos;
            willmsg.destinationName = lwTopic;
            willmsg.retained = lwRetain;
            options.willMessage = willmsg;
        }

        this.client.connect(options);
    },

    'onConnect': function () {
        websocketclient.connected = true;
        console.log("connected");
        var body = $('body').addClass('connected').removeClass('notconnected').removeClass('connectionbroke');

        websocketclient.render.hide('conni');
        websocketclient.render.show('publish');
        websocketclient.render.show('sub');
        websocketclient.render.show('messages');
    },

    'onFail': function (message) {
        websocketclient.connected = false;
        console.log("error: " + message.errorMessage);
        websocketclient.render.showError('Connect failed: ' + message.errorMessage);
    },

    'onConnectionLost': function (responseObject) {
        websocketclient.connected = false;
        if (responseObject.errorCode !== 0) {
            console.log("onConnectionLost:" + responseObject.errorMessage);
        }
        $('body.connected').removeClass('connected').addClass('notconnected').addClass('connectionbroke');
        websocketclient.render.show('conni');
        websocketclient.render.hide('publish');
        websocketclient.render.hide('sub');
        websocketclient.render.hide('messages');

        //Cleanup messages
        websocketclient.messages = [];
        websocketclient.render.clearMessages();

        //Cleanup subscriptions
        websocketclient.subscriptions = [];
        websocketclient.render.clearSubscriptions();
    },

    'onMessageArrived': function (message) {
//        console.log("onMessageArrived:" + message.payloadString + " qos: " + message.qos);

        var subscription = websocketclient.getSubscriptionForTopic(message.destinationName);

        var messageObj = {
            'topic': message.destinationName,
            'retained': message.retained,
            'qos': message.qos,
            'payload': message.payloadString,
            'timestamp': moment(),
            'subscriptionId': subscription.id,
            'color': websocketclient.getColorForSubscription(subscription.id)
        };

        console.log(messageObj);
        messageObj.id = websocketclient.render.message(messageObj);
        websocketclient.messages.push(messageObj);
    },

    'disconnect': function () {
        this.client.disconnect();
    },

    'publish': function (topic, payload, qos, retain) {

        if (!websocketclient.connected) {
            websocketclient.render.showError("Not connected");
            return false;
        }

        var message = new Messaging.Message(payload);
        message.destinationName = topic;
        message.qos = qos;
        message.retained = retain;
        this.client.send(message);
    },

    'subscribe': function (topic, qosNr, color) {

        if (!websocketclient.connected) {
            websocketclient.render.showError("Not connected");
            return false;
        }

        if (topic.length < 1) {
            websocketclient.render.showError("Topic cannot be empty");
            return false;
        }

        if (_.find(this.subscriptions, { 'topic': topic })) {
            websocketclient.render.showError('You are already subscribed to this topic');
            return false;
        }

        this.client.subscribe(topic, {qos: qosNr});
        if (color.length < 1) {
            color = '999999';
        }

        var subscription = {'topic': topic, 'qos': qosNr, 'color': color};
        subscription.id = websocketclient.render.subscription(subscription);
        this.subscriptions.push(subscription);
        return true;
    },

    'unsubscribe': function (id) {
        var subs = _.find(websocketclient.subscriptions, {'id': id});
        this.client.unsubscribe(subs.topic);
        websocketclient.subscriptions = _.filter(websocketclient.subscriptions, function (item) {
            return item.id != id;
        });

        websocketclient.render.removeSubscriptionsMessages(id);
    },

    'deleteSubscription': function (id) {
        var elem = $("#sub" + id);

        if (confirm('Are you sure ?')) {
            elem.remove();
            this.unsubscribe(id);
        }
    },

    'getRandomColor': function () {
        var r = (Math.round(Math.random() * 255)).toString(16);
        var g = (Math.round(Math.random() * 255)).toString(16);
        var b = (Math.round(Math.random() * 255)).toString(16);
        return r + g + b;
    },

    'getSubscriptionForTopic': function (topic) {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < this.subscriptions.length; i++) {
            if (this.compareTopics(topic, this.subscriptions[i].topic)) {
                return this.subscriptions[i];
            }
        }
        return false;
    },

    'getColorForPublishTopic': function (topic) {
        var id = this.getSubscriptionForTopic(topic);
        return this.getColorForSubscription(id);
    },

    'getColorForSubscription': function (id) {
        try {
            if (!id) {
                return '99999';
            }

            var sub = _.find(this.subscriptions, { 'id': id });
            if (!sub) {
                return '999999';
            } else {
                return sub.color;
            }
        } catch (e) {
            return '999999';
        }
    },

    'compareTopics': function (topic, subTopic) {
        var pattern = subTopic.replace("+", "(.*?)").replace("#", "(.*)");
        var regex = new RegExp("^" + pattern + "$");
        return regex.test(topic);
    },

    'render': {

        'showError': function (message) {
            alert(message);
        },
        'messages': function () {

            websocketclient.render.clearMessages();
            _.forEach(websocketclient.messages, function (message) {
                message.id = websocketclient.render.message(message);
            });

        },
        'message': function (message) {

            var largest = websocketclient.lastMessageId++;

            var html = '<li class="messLine id="' + largest + '">' +
                '   <div class="row large-12 mess' + largest + '" style="border-left: solid 10px #' + message.color + '; ">' +
                '       <div class="large-12 columns messageText">' +
                '           <div class="large-3 columns date">' + message.timestamp.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss") + '</div>' +
                '           <div class="large-5 columns topicM truncate" id="topicM' + largest + '" title="' + Encoder.htmlEncode(message.topic, 0) + '">Topic: ' + Encoder.htmlEncode(message.topic) + '</div>' +
                '           <div class="large-2 columns qos">Qos: ' + message.qos + '</div>' +
                '           <div class="large-2 columns retain">';
            if (message.retained) {
                html += 'Retained';
            }
            html += '           </div>' +
                '           <div class="large-12 columns message break-words">' + Encoder.htmlEncode(message.payload) + '</div>' +
                '       </div>' +
                '   </div>' +
                '</li>';
            $("#messEdit").prepend(html);
            return largest;
        },

        'subscriptions': function () {
            websocketclient.render.clearSubscriptions();
            _.forEach(websocketclient.subscriptions, function (subs) {
                subs.id = websocketclient.render.subscription(subs);
            });
        },

        'subscription': function (subscription) {
            var largest = websocketclient.lastSubId++;
            $("#innerEdit").append(
                '<li class="subLine" id="sub' + largest + '">' +
                    '   <div class="row large-12 subs' + largest + '" style="border-left: solid 10px #' + subscription.color + '; background-color: #ffffff">' +
                    '       <div class="large-12 columns subText">' +
                    '           <div class="large-1 columns right closer">' +
                    '              <a href="#" onclick="websocketclient.deleteSubscription(' + largest + '); return false;">x</a>' +
                    '           </div>' +
                    '           <div class="qos">Qos: ' + subscription.qos + '</div>' +
                    '           <div class="topic truncate" id="topic' + largest + '" title="' + Encoder.htmlEncode(subscription.topic, 0) + '">' + Encoder.htmlEncode(subscription.topic) + '</div>' +
                    '       </div>' +
                    '   </div>' +
                    '</li>');
            return largest;
        },

        'toggleAll': function () {
            websocketclient.render.toggle('conni');
            websocketclient.render.toggle('publish');
            websocketclient.render.toggle('messages');
            websocketclient.render.toggle('sub');
        },

        'toggle': function (name) {
            $('.' + name + 'Arrow').toggleClass("closed");
            $('.' + name + 'Top').toggleClass("closed");
            var elem = $('#' + name + 'Main');
            elem.slideToggle();
        },

        'hide': function (name) {
            $('.' + name + 'Arrow').addClass("closed");
            $('.' + name + 'Top').addClass("closed");
            var elem = $('#' + name + 'Main');
            elem.slideUp();
        },

        'show': function (name) {
            $('.' + name + 'Arrow').removeClass("closed");
            $('.' + name + 'Top').removeClass("closed");
            var elem = $('#' + name + 'Main');
            elem.slideDown();
        },

        'removeSubscriptionsMessages': function (id) {
            websocketclient.messages = _.filter(websocketclient.messages, function (item) {
                return item.subscriptionId != id;
            });
            websocketclient.render.messages();
        },

        'clearMessages': function () {
            $("#messEdit").empty();
        },

        'clearSubscriptions': function () {
            $("#innerEdit").empty();
        }
    }
};
```

---

Comment: Can you post your javascript code ?

Comment: @SantoshBalaji I have added some relevant code. Sorry for not including any earlier, as the code was the website's source I thought it would have been unnecessary to add it to the question. In this case I have not included the `paho-mqtt.js` and `mqttws31.js`, because it took the question over the word limit.

Answer (score 0):

I think I am a bit late...but I leave here for posterity.

The Paho JS library has undergo a series of changes before release 1.0.3 and the last one 1.1.0.

If you refer to a `mqttws31.js` probably you was using a version earlier than 1.0.3, because from 1.0.3 the main js file was renamed to `paho-mqtt.js`.
Can be the reason why something in your code was working differently from HiveMQ version.

I tried to sum the situation [here](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.javascript/issues/232#issuecomment-950232236)